# Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.v15.2,

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

My project is asp.net web forms version 4.5.1 hosted on a web server with plesk cpanel.

i have deployed my site using visual studio "publish website" option from "Build" menu in visual studio.

everything is fine on local.

now when i try to access my [first page](http://behdoctor.ir/home.aspx) that is in a root folder everything is OK but when I want to access a page that is within a sub folder I got this error.(mentioned in the question title)

[this](http://behdoctor.ir/insurance_price_query_pages/default.aspx) is one of those pages with error.

DX is really annoying and I think it is not worth to use it. adding a button component from DX adds a table with lots of JS script while you could do it with a single html input element. never mind.

[image: error screenshot]

please guide me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special tool in DevExpress that generates all the needed assemblies for ASP.NET in order to be copied to the directory when the website is Deployed.

Source : [Devexpress](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument14777)

**The "Could not load file or assembly 'X'" error message appears Problem Description:**

> Ensure that you have copied all required DevExpress assemblies into
>   the web site's Bin folder after deploying it to the production
>   machine. A detailed description of the deployment process, as well as
>   the list of assemblies required by the ASP.NET and MVC products can be
>   found in the [Redistributable Assemblies (ASP.NET and MVC
>   Deployment](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/CustomDocument4834.aspx)) documentation article.

Comment: what is that special tool and where to get that? i can load devexpress components but only can not load them for pages inside virtual directories.